# react life cycle: getDefaultProps called before ReactDOM.render ？

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

when testing react lifecycle，I found a quite strange but confusing issue:

```
var TestLifeCycle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function(){
        console.log('2');
    },
    getDefaultProps : function(){
        console.log('1');
    },
    render : function(){
        return null;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<TestLifeCycle test="hello world!"/>, document.body);
```

the result is :

```
1
Warning: render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation issues. 
2
```

pay attention to the warning:
`getDefaultProps` will called at very beginning in the react lifecycle. In my understanding, the right console log order is :

```
warning 
1
2
```

but under chrome is :

```
1
warning 
2
```

Does `getDefaultProps` called even before than `ReactDOM.render` ?

Comment: yes，getInitialState and  getDefaultProps are called before render. My point is the order : pay attention to the warning position. I think is [warning-->1 -->2]. but console is [1-->warning-->2]. how to understand the order ? by the way : document.body is not suggested by react.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`getDefaultProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) is called before `render`.
As mentioned in the documentation, it is called when the class is created and stored statically:

> The result of getDefaultProps() will be cached and used to ensure that
>   this.props.value will have a value if it was not specified by the
>   parent component.

What is important to understand with React is that there is three different layers. While most OOP only use Classes and instances, in react you have *Components*, *Elements* and *Instances*. It is often a bit confusing at first.

Components are the "class", i.e. the general specifications of what you want to create. Instances are the rendered version of this specification, i.e. the DOM nodes. In react, you rarely manipulate instances directly, what you are mostly working with is elements.

The element is an "intermediate" layer that define how a particular component element should be rendered, before it is rendered. This is what you get when you write `var elt = (<MyComponent prop1="bidule">)`.
Elements are plain JavaScript objects with some properties (props, key, ref, & type). So the properties are already there, long before the actual rendering anyway.

Read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) or [here](https://medium.com/@fay_jai/react-elements-vs-react-components-vs-component-backing-instances-14d42729f62#.e9yc63eno) for more information about Components, Elements and instances.

Answer (score 0):

`getDefaultProps` is called before `render` method. This is the correct behavior. You can assert this by doing the following:

```
var TestLifeCycle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function(){
        console.log('2');
    },
    getDefaultProps : function(){
        console.log('1');
        return {className:'Test'}
    },
    render : function(){
        return null;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<TestLifeCycle className={this.props.className} test="hello world!"/>, document.body);
```

If we go by your assumption and think `render` is called first. Then `this.props.className` will be `undefined` at this stage.

So the react calls `getDefaultProps` to see if there are any default props to use and then substitutes them internally and renders the component correctly.

For more about other components and their lifecycle refer to :
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops

Comment: yes，getInitialState and  getDefaultProps are called before render.